# Pandas replacing all column values with nan

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a pandas dataframe that contains a column populated by 3 object values: "true","false", and "---"

I want to replace the "true" values with 0, and the "false" values with 1, so I wrote the following

```
df['True/False'] = df['True/False'].str.replace('False' '1')
df['True/False'] = df['True/False'].str.replace('True', '0')
```

So, I would expect input `['False','True','False','False','False','---']`
to return `[1,0,1,1,1,'---']` when I `print(df['True/False'])`.

But instead I get:

`["NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN","NaN"]`

A little help?

Comment: you are better off using the general `.replace` rather than `str.replace`. So `df['True/False'] = df['True/False'].replace({'False':1,'True':0})`

Comment: also, missing a comma after `'False'` in your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `df.replace`, you should use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) as it is much faster:

Create a `dict` of values you want to replace:

```
In [3590]: d = {'True': 0, 'False': 1}
```

Consider `df`:

```
In [3592]: df = pd.DataFrame(['False','True','False','False','False','---'], columns=['A'])

In [3593]: df
Out[3593]: 
       A
0  False
1   True
2  False
3  False
4  False
5    ---

In [3597]: df.A = df.A.map(d).fillna(df.A)

In [3598]: df
Out[3598]: 
     A
0    1
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    1
5  ---
```